# Why does type.Assembly.GetType(type.Name) return null?

Tags: c#

```
Type type = typeof(MyType);
Type copy = type.Assembly.GetType(type.Name);
```

It seems trivial to me that above code should end up with `copy` being another reference to the same object as `type`. However, I keep getting `copy == null`. If I use the overload `Assembly.GetType(type.Name, true)` it throws a `TypeLoadException`.

Isn't it weird that the assembly of the type can't find this type? It's definitely in there though! The following are both true:

```
type.Assembly.GetTypes()[0] == type;
type.Assembly.GetExportedTypes()[0] == type;
```

If this is expected behavior, can anyone explain why so?

If it is not, could anyone point me to anything that may cause this to happen?

---

Super simple demo:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var type = typeof(Program);
        Console.WriteLine(type.Assembly.GetExportedTypes()[0] == type); // True
        Console.WriteLine(type.Assembly.GetType(type.Name, true)); // exception
    }
}
```

Comment: If you [peek at the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see why.

Comment: The documentation (and I suspect Intellisense) says that `name` is `the full name of the type`, ie. including the namespace, not the simple name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Type.Name` isn't quite enough to identify the type.

For example, `typeof(string).Name` will give you `String` - but there's no namespace.

To get the full type name including the namespace, you need to use `Type.FullName` instead. If you also care about different assemblies, a fully qualified name is the best - `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`.

A few examples of the use of `Type.GetType`:

```
var a = Type.GetType("String"); // Returns null - not enough information to find the type
var b = Type.GetType("System.String"); // typeof(string), because mscorlib is loaded
var c = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Form, System.Windows.Forms");
        // Works even when System.Windows.Forms isn't loaded

var d = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Form, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
        // Also checks for proper version and signature. 
        // This is System.Windows.Forms from Microsoft.
```

Comment: Obv. OP won´t care for different assemblies because he´s just interested on the assembly the given type is located in. Having said this, not `Type.GetType` is relevant here but `Assembly.GetType`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere it makes no difference. Assembly.GetType expects the full name.

Comment: exactly. `var copy = type.Assembly.GetType(type.FullName)` would do the trick.

Comment: Your code is therefor quite misleading because you´re providing fully qualified name including the actual assembly (ar least within your last example).

Answer (score 1):

As from the docu of `Assembly.GetType`:

> This method only searches the current assembly instance. The name parameter includes the namespace but not the assembly.

Having said this provide the `FullName` of the given type:

```
Type type = typeof(MyType);
Type copy = type.Assembly.GetType(type.FullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the`FullName` of your type:

```
var copy = type.Assembly.GetType(type.FullName)
```